# Proof that continuous $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ satisfying $f(x) = -f(-x)$ represents an injection on homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm looking to prove that continuous functions $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ satisfying $f(x) = -f(-x)$ for all $x \in S^1$ represent injections on homology.

I'm trying to prove this fact on the way to proving the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, and I really don't know where to start (although I *do* know alternative proofs of Borsuk-Ulam).

I'm guessing the map $g(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{\|f(x) - f(-x)\|}$ will appear at some point. Also, we know the homology groups of $S^1$, namely $\mathbb{Z}$ at $0$ and $1$, and $0$ elsewhere. But as for the actual statement we're trying to prove, I don't see how to begin.

Comment: I've edited the question into the body of my post. Also, I mean $f(x) = -f(-x)$ for all $x \in S^1$. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, thanks :-)

Comment: A proof of a generalization of this fact is presented in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book. The idea is to prove that a map which such property has odd degree, and so cannot be null. Anyway the proof require the use of homology with coefficient in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.
Are you looking for some more direct proof?

Comment: Wait, is it sufficient to show that $f$ is not nullhomotopic?